# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'production'

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, modulenotfounderror

I am learning AI from MIT OCW's 6.034(fall 2010) and while coding they used:

```
from production import IF, AND, OR, NOT, THEN, DELETE, forward_chain
theft_rule = IF( 'you have (?x)',
 THEN( 'i have (?x)' ),
 DELETE( 'you have (?x)' ))
data = ( 'you have apple',
 'you have orange',
 'you have pear' )
print forward_chain([theft_rule], data, verbose=True)
```

And to do the problem set, I am expected to use production module but I am getting ModuleNotFoundError.
I have tried to look online for the module but there are no mentions of it anywhere except ocw. I don't know what to do.

Link to the pdf where this module is introduced:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-034-artificial-intelligence-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_034F10_lab1.pdf

Comment: `production` might be a local module that came with the files of the course?

Comment: Try `pip3 install production`, and if that doesn't work then as @dkreeft said, maybe it's included with the course?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you acess the "Assignment" webpage of the course you can download the zip files of the task "lab01", where the script production.py is alocated.

Also, after reading the header of the Lab 0, I'm a bit concerned that, since you didn't used the tester.py of the lab00, you may not have done the proper testes for your code.

[image: webpage of your course]